# swift 2 dictionary is ambigious without more context

Tags: xcode, swift

in converting to swift 2 from 1.2 i'm getting an error, type of expression is ambiguous without more context.

```
        var recordSettings = [
        AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
        AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
        AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey : 32,
        AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey : true
```

I have no idea what the problem is . I've tried casting to [String:AnyObject] but with no luck. any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type inferencer is having trouble realizing that `kAudioFormatLinearPCM` is an alias for `UInt32` *and* that that can be boxed in an `NSNumber`.

So help it:

```
var recordSettings:[String:AnyObject] = [
  AVFormatIDKey: NSNumber(unsignedInt: kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
  AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0,
  AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
  AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey : 32,
  AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey : true]
```